# imagemagick pdf is not converting into a image

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, imagick

```
<?php 
class Pdf_to_img extends CI_Controller{
public function converter(){
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config = array(
    'image_library' => 'imagemagick',
    'library_path' => 'D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16',
    'source_image' => 'theme/assets/pdf/ci.pdf' ,
    'new_image' => 'theme/assets/img/copy.jpg' ,
    'maintain_ratio' => true,
    'width' => 980,
    'quality' => '90%',
   );

   $this->image_lib->initialize( $config );

   if ( $this->image_lib->resize( ) ) {
    $this->image_lib->clear( );
   }
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Friends as i'm new to codeigniter , i'm converting a pdf file into image while surfing i've got this piece of code i've altered all the location but while executing i'm recieving the error as

**The path to the image is not correct.
Image processing failed. Please verify that your server supports the chosen protocol and that the path to your image library is correct.**

So please correct my code if there is any error or any code to be added to make the change

I've installed the ImageMagick ON **D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16**

and source_image path is **D:\wamp\www\login\theme\assets\pdf**

and new image path is **D:\wamp\www\login\theme\assets\img**

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the imagickphp library is installed first. Then uses the following commands:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage('mytest.pdf');
$imagick->writeImage('output.jpg');
```